# Why `UIFont.boldSystemFont` is not `UIFontWeightBold`?

Tags: ios, swift

I've been used `UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize:)` for a while.

And I thought It is the same of `UIFont.systemFont(ofSize:, weight: UIFontWeightBold)`,
But It was the same of `UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize:, weight: UIFontWeightSemibold)`

Is it a bug? or just a legacy?

[image]

Comment: its not any bug, perhaps flexibility of language.

Comment: Probably neither, it works as intended, it is only your expectation that is off - there is no guarantee that `boldSystemFont` would use `UIFontWeightBold`, why should there be such guarantee? Your assumption that `boldSystemFont` *should* be using the `UIFontWeightBold` is just wrong. Maybe some time ago that was the case - but that is basically the purpose of the method, to be able to change the underlying logic while keeping the function name, that is probably why the method is not called `systemFontWithFontWeightBold`.

Comment: I agree with @luk2302. Constant Font Weights are just some predefined values which vary from [-1, 1], and are added there just for the ease of use, due to that [most fonts do not include all these variants.](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uifontdescriptor/font_weights)